# Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008

I installed VS 2008 and then installed SQL server 2005 and choose desktop tools but Management Studio does not show up.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you talking about the SQL Management Studio? I just downloaded it and installed it rather than wasting my time with the installer on the VS disc. It's available somewhere on MS's site.

Comment: So you downloadeded AND installed, rather than install?  Sounds like a real time-saver :D

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, after the visual studio and sql installer on the CD didn't do the job, I just downloaded the .msi installer of SQL management studio and ran that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install SQL then visual studio; until V2008 SP1 that was the case for SQL 2008 as well. You might be able to add the tools using add remove programs; if that doesnt work remove VS2008; install management tools; install VS2008 again.